# What is the difference between these two coordinate conversions?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, angle, spherical-coordinates

I'm trying to understand spherical coordinates but this is confusing me. To convert longitude ($\theta$) and latitude ($\phi$) to cartesian coordinates, I've seen two formulas.

$X = \cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)$

$Y = \cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)$

$Z = \sin(\phi)$

---

$X = \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$

$Y = \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$

$Z = \cos(\phi)$

which one is the correct way or why these two methods exist?

Comment: Assuming the $z$-axis goes through the north/south poles: Since latitude $\phi$ measures north/south positions, $Z$ should depend on $\phi$ and $\phi$ only. So $Z=\sin(\theta)$ is ruled out. This one would have $Z$ changing as you travel east/west. We might see different versions if some authors use $\theta,\phi$ for latitude/longitude, and some use them the other way around. We also might see different versions if different authors measure $\phi$ from the equator vs. a pole. For example, in the second group here, $\phi=0$ has $Z=\cos(0)=1$, the north pole.

Comment: If we're using the term "latitude," I would think we would want $\phi=0$ to be at the equator, in which case we could have $$X=\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta),$$ $$Y=\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta),$$ $$Z=\sin(\phi).$$ This would have $-\pi/2\leqslant \phi\leqslant \pi/2$. We would be on the equator at $\phi=0$. This is like your first group, but with $\theta$ and $\phi$ reversed.

Comment: @user469053 Thanks, I've just realized I made a mistake in the first formula. I've fixed that. now it looks like yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between these two groups of formulas is where $\phi=0$ is. The first group has $Z=\sin(0)=0$ (the equator) when $\phi=0$, and the second group has $Z=\cos(0)=1$ (the north pole) when $\phi=0$. It's just a convention of whether you measure your angles from the equator or from the north pole. If the word "latitude" is used, it *might* be preferable to use the first group, since the non-mathematical definition of "latitude" measures from the equator.

Comment: Now I understand. so If I want to measure latitude from the equator I can replace $\phi$ with $\pi/2-\phi$ in the second formula and I've checked if i do that it turns into the first formula. now makes sense. Thanks a lot